# Prove the number of roots of polynomial $Q(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

> Let $P$ be a polynomial, it has $n$ distinct real roots and all these roots are larger than 1. Let 
>   $$
> Q(x)=(x^2+1)P(x)P'(x)+x[(P(x))^2+(P'(x))^2].
> $$
>   Prove $Q(x)$ has at least $2n-1$ distinct real roots.

I start to find $Q(x)=0$ between two roots. Assume $P(x)<0$ in $(x_1,x_2)$ and $P(x_1)=P(x_2)=0$. There exists a minimal value at $\xi\in(x_1,x_2)$ s.t. 
$$
P(\xi)<0, P'(\xi)=0, P''(\xi)>0.
$$
Then I get $P(\xi)+P'(\xi)<0$.

It can be deduced by contradiction that not all $x\in (x_1,x_2)$ satisfy $P(x)+P'(x)\leq 0$. Hence there exists $\eta$ s.t. $P(\eta)+P'(\eta)>0$, then there exists $\alpha$ s.t. 
$$P(\alpha)+P'(\alpha)=0.$$
 $Q(\alpha)<2xP(\alpha)P'(\alpha)+x[((P(\alpha))^2+(P'(\alpha))^2]\leq 0$, i.e. 
$$Q(\alpha)<0.$$
 If I have $Q(x_1)>0$ and $Q(x_2)>0$ then by mean value theorem there are two roots in $(x_1,x_2)$.

The problems of this thought are:

(1) Even I have two roots in every interval, only $2n-2$ roots be found;

(2) $Q(x_1)>0$ and $Q(x_2)>0$ may be zero and my process would be useless?

Hope someone give me an answer or a hint.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Thank you! I've updated.

Comment: Does your assumption implicitly imply that $P$ has degree $n$, i.e. all roots are of multiplicitly one?

Comment: @MooS I'd doubt tahat. In fact, any multiple root of $P$ is a common root of $P$ and $P'$, hence also a root of $Q$.

Comment: Neither are mentioned in the book. Hence no degree and multipilicity restriction. @MooS

Comment: if $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ then $deg[h(x)]=deg[f(x)]+deg[g(x)]$ and if $deg[f(x)]=n $ then $deg[f'(x)]=n-1$ since f is a polynomial?  Correct?  does this help at all?

Comment: @AmateurMathGuy It helps me solve the question! Thank you.

Comment: @yahoo well I can only go as far as $$\begin{align} Q(x)&=(x^2+1)P(x)P'(x)+x[(P(x))^2+(P'(x))^2] \\ deg[Q(x)]&=deg\left\lbrace(x^2+1)P(x)P'(x)+x[(P(x))^2+(P'(x))^2]\right\rbrace \\ deg[Q(x)] &\leq max\left\{deg\left[(x^2+1)P(x)P'(x)\right], deg\left[ x\cdot(P(x))^2],deg[x\cdot(P'(x))^2\right]\right\} \\ deg[Q(x)]&\leq max\{2+ n +(n-1),1+2n, 1+2(n-1)\} \\  deg[Q(x)] &\leq 2n+1\end{align}$$ So perhaps you can help me understand how I helped you

Comment: @AmateurMathGuy I've accepted an answer that gives two hints to completely sove the question. Its idea is the same as yours(use the property of polynomial's degree, and get the degree of $Q(x)$ is odd).

Comment: @yahoo ahh ok glad I can help.  Being helpful isn't a guarantee on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ad (1): Note that $P(x)$ and $P'(x)$ have opposite signs for $x\ll 0$, hence $Q(x)<0$ for $x\ll 0$. But at the first real root $x_0$ of $P$, we have $Q(x_0)=x_0P'(x_0)^2\ge0$ because $x_0\ge1$. Thus there is an additional root of $Q$ in $(-\infty,x_0]$.

Ad (2): If $P(x_i)=0$, then $Q(x_i)=x_iP'(x_i)^2\ge 0$. Hence if both $x_i$ are only simple roots, then we obtain two distinct root insinde $(x_1,x_2)$. Whereas if $P(x_i)$ is a $k$-fold root, $k\ge 2$, then $x_i$ is a precisely $(2k-2)$-fold root of $Q$. So first of all, the $Q(x_i)$ count as distinct roots by themselves (but that''s too few). But at least we know that $Q$ has no sign change at $x_i$. Does that help?

Answer (score 4):

I claim that $$H(x) := \frac{Q}{xP(x)P'(x)} = \frac{x^2+1}{x}+\frac{P^2+P'^2}{PP'}$$ has at least $2n-2$ roots in its range of definition. Then in particular $Q$ has at least $2n-2$ roots.

As you have proposed, we fix two roots $x_1 < x_2$ with no more roots in between them and some intermediate value $a$ with $P'(a)=0$ (Rolle's Theorem).

Let us assume $P(a) > 0$, the other case is dealt with the same way.

Then $P'<0$ in $(a,x_2)$.

Note that $|P(a)| > |P'(a)|$ but $|P(x_2)| \leq |P'(x_2)|$, hence at some point in $(a,x_2)$ we have $|P|=|P'|$. At this point we have $|\frac{P^2+P'^2}{PP'}| =2$ and thus $\frac{P^2+P'^2}{PP'}=-2$. We also know $\frac{x^2+1}{x}>2$ in $(a,x_2)$, because $x>1$.

Hence $H>0$ at this point and clearly $\lim\limits_{x \to a, x>a} H = -\infty = \lim\limits_{x \to x_2, x<x_2} H$, thus we obtain two roots of $H$ in $(a,x_2)$ by the intermediate value theorem.

---

Doing this for any two adjacent roots of $P$, this addds up to $2n-2$ roots, i.e $Q$ has at least $2n-2$ roots.

**Here comes the punchline:** $Q$ is a polynomial of odd degree, hence the number of real roots is odd. Thus having at least $2n-2$ real roots actually ensures having at least $2n-1$ roots.

Comment: I agree that $\bigg|\frac{P^2+P'^2}{PP'}\bigg| =2$ , but how do you see that $\frac{P^2+P'^2}{PP'}=-2$ and not $+2$ ?

Comment: $P$ is positive and $P'$ is negative in $(a,x_2)$, hence the fraction is negative.

Comment: I see now, thanks.